# Monolog: Send errors to Sentry with preserved lower-level log records

Tags: php, sentry, monolog

**The goal:**

I want to send all ERROR+ Monolog records to Sentry along with lower-level records (for easier debugging what's happening) and they should be all sent as one event.

**What I have:**

I have Symfony4 app with `config/packages/prod/monolog.yaml`:

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        # there is also fingers_crossed for file logging, but it is rather not related

        sentry_buffer:
            type: fingers_crossed
            action_level: error
            handler: sentry_transparent
            # ignore records logged by exception listener
            channels: ["!exceptions"]
        sentry_transparent:
            type: whatfailuregroup
            members: [sentry]
        sentry:
            type:  raven
            # Use Sentry client registered by SentryBundle
            client_id: sentry.client
            level: debug
            auto_log_stacks: true
```

I have custom exception listener which creates JSON response but before sending it's also logging error to the `exceptions` channel (so I exclude this channel in `fingers_crossed` handler so I don't get duplicates.

It's working locally - Sentry events are created only when ERROR+ records occurs in Monolog and all collected logs are attached in record's context.

Somehow on production we got maaaaaaany events with `info` level and it does not make sense:

[image]

These events are not related to any error but in breadcrumbs I see there is some deprecation error triggered:

[image]

I've tried to reproduce this with `trigger_error` like in `ProcessBuilder` (from breadcrumbs) but whatever I do I don't get INFO events in my Sentry.

Those events are from long-running processes (Enqueue consumers), but I did all the steps from production (request, processing queue) and I don't get result as in our production instance.

Any suggestions what's going on? How can I improve our config to achieve what we need but without spamming our Sentry with events we don't want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to add `BufferHandler` between `FingersCrossedHandler` and `WhatFailureGroupHandler`:

```
sentry_wait_for_error:
    type:         fingers_crossed
    action_level: error
    handler:      sentry_buffer
    excluded_http_codes:
        4xx: ~
sentry_buffer: # All records must be sent at once!
    type:    buffer
    handler: sentry_failure_handler
sentry_failure_handler:
    type: whatfailuregroup
    members: [sentry]
sentry:
    type:  raven
    dsn: '%env(SENTRY_DSN)%'
    level: debug
    auto_log_stacks: true
    release: '%env(APP_VERSION)%'
```

Comment: Actually the solution was to configure `stop_buffering` for fingers crossed handler, which pass all records after first activation.